# Importing bootstrap utilities and missing order

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I just want to use utility classes and I'm importing **bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6**. When I search files in node_modules, I can't find any "order-" utility rules there.

Was that removed? In documentation, there should be order utility classes - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks

Comment: ?? why are you not importing the latest ?? it stands there for instance :  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I don't want to import last version, because I do want to make sure everything works with my version in my dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

First, update to the latest version of bootstrap.

Second, the version you are using does not use `order-*` classes. It rather uses flex ordering using `flex-*` classes. Refer [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#flex-order).

Comment: That's what I found. Thanks. I'm surpriced that they removed it.